# HttpURLConnection getting content length from server

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I using the following connection to resume my download:

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setReadTimeout(7000);
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + localFileSize + "-");

long fileLengthOnServer = connection.getContentLength();
connection.connect();
```

The value of the `fileLengthOnServer` is `-1`. Can anyone explain that in which conditions `fileLengthOnServer` becomes `-1`. I guess, but not sure that the `localFileSize` is the same as the one on the server. Please help!

Answer (score 2):

You need to call this `long fileLengthOnServer = connection.getContentLength();` after `connection.connect()`. You can't get the response headers without connecting to the server first

Comment: You don't really need to call connection.connect(), as by calling openConnection method, it is already in connected state, and connect call will be ignored as per the documentation of connect() method. Might be problem with the response streams.